# Bitly, convert localhost URL cause error INVALID_ARG_LONG_URL, is it expected?

Tags: node.js, url, url-shortener, bitly

I am testing bitly in development environment with bitly package from npmjs, when I run `bitly.shorten(link)`, I get the following error message:

```json
{
  "message": "INVALID_ARG_LONG_URL",
  "resource": "bitlinks",
  "description": "The value provided is invalid.",
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "long_url",
      "error_code": "invalid"
    }
  ]
}
```

The shortened url is `http://localhost:3000/file/cto/pdf/en/2020-11-19/Presentation-Customer-AREVA-Hydrolic.pdf`

Does bitly forbid the conversion of `localhost` links ?

I have tried to add `https` instead of `http` and this didn't work, I have checked at their documentation and didn't see any restriction.

I tought bitly was made for shortening long url.

Is this expected to fail or will it fail in production environment too since the URL is too long?

Answer (score 8):

Use `http://127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

replace `localhost` with your IP. bitly do not entertain `localhost`

In your case make your url like:

```
http://10.10.10.10:3000/file/cto/pdf/en/2020-11-19/Presentation-Customer-AREVA-Hydrolic.pdf
```